# how to remove use strict from rollup bundle processed by babel

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, rollupjs

I tried plugin transform-remove-strict-mode but it doesn't worked. Result format is iife and I'm using rollup in gulp (and babel as a rollup plugin).

Comment: ES6 modules are strict by default. Are you using ES6 module syntax?

Comment: Try passing the `useStrict: false` option to Rollup. Better yet, don't use code that doesn't run in strict mode!

Comment: Can you provide some link with : es6 modules are strict only ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, my code is dependant on non strict behavior...

Answer (score 13):

Use `strict: false` in the `output` options as per
[the documentation](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputstrict).

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I still get an error `Deleting local variable in strict mode delete fn ` when trying to use a third party SDK. The SDK works fine in webpack, but importing and attempting to call methods within a svelte + rollup project give the error above. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 5):

Just make sure you specify `strict: false` in the config output object.

```
input: [...],
output: {
    ...,
    strict: false,
},
plugins: [...],
```

You can see the default options here:
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files

Answer (score 1):

adding `useStrict: false` to rollup config did the job