this in an IIFE is undefined when building with vite
I have tried to migrate a CRA to vite. One remaining obstacle is a dependency of a dependency that has this code:
var requestFrame = (function () {
  var window = this
  var raf = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  //...and so on and so forth
})()

this is undefined and the first thing it tries to invoke (requestAnimationFrame) throws. The page, depending on a dependency that depends on this seems to have worked fine before so I'm suspecting that something can be configured in vite to fix this, but i'm not sure what to be looking for.

Your code looks like it was written to run in non-strict mode, but the new context is strict. That's whjy this is undefined.

It's not my code, it's what some npm package that i depend on, depends :(
Can i exclude this particular package somehow from the strictness ?

Well if you're using ES modules (import and export instead of require()) then the code is always in strict mode.

I dont know much about this stuff, most of the javascript i wrote just kinda assumes these things are there. If i try to require my dependency this may work?

It totally did not work :(

npm packages are for node.js. This code for running in the browser, not the server.

This is running in node. Node is failing to produce code that would run in the browser. This is really not helpful.

Maybe turning strict mode off in the rollup config? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378674/how-to-remove-use-strict-from-rollup-bundle-processed-by-babel

Did not work :(

@Barmar: That’s not true – npm packages are often for browsers, or multiplatform.

a common IIFE pattern is (function(window) { .... code ... })(window) - but you state This is running in node ... there is no window, so that won't work either

Node is failing to produce code that would run in the browser. node doesn't do that. What produces code that runs in the browser is a combination of vite and you

I thought that vite is running in node, this is incorrect? I also thought that all software i write depends on me, is this also a wrong assumption? The combination of vite and myself is implied by mentioning the tag vite and posting under my username? Sorry, i'm not good at this stuff, i just want some react to run :)

Or, i guess, how would you respond to this statement npm packages are for node.js. This code for running in the browser, not the server.
For years i've been building JS code that runs in the browser, using JS code that runs in node, by writing my own JS code :( "npm packages" have always been a part of that, and would always ultimately run in the browser.

My ultimate conclusion is that i wrote a patch file and that im using a node js to execute one npm package that patches another npm package, and that patched code runs in a browser. Im a happy camper :D

Node.js is a javascript runtime on desktop/server. It can be used to run a desktop/server application. On the other hand, it can also be used as a tool to generate js code that runs in browser. That is what most frontend framework do. They are themselves some js libraries runs on your development machine (i.e. node.js running on desktop), taking whatever you wrote as input (ts,tsx,vue,svelte, etc.) then spit out some html/js files for you to host on a server. In short, they use node.js to prduce js files that don't run on node.js.

Npm hosts a mix of node.js libraries, browser libraries, cross-platform libraries and even some framework-specific libraries or other runtime-specific libraries. That's one thing people love and hate at the same time about npm. You don't immediately know whether a library you pull from npm will work on your target platform. Usually the library developers are kind enough to mention which platform their library support in readme, and library user should pay attention to select libraries that support your target platform.

By the way if you ever found a library just have some slight issue for you, you can always fork it or clone it locally, modify it and add your modified version as dependency.

I found the patch to be less intrusive.  The process was pretty simple. I modified a file inside of /node_modules ran the script and it generated a diff. I wont have to think about this package ever again hopefully.

@RickyMo The environment never changed. This library always ran in the browser. I swapped out some build tool, it could had been a custom transpiler written in rust or brainfuck, it wouldnt matter. I dont expect something like three.js to run on a server. I dont expect something using fs and whatnot to run on a webpage. This was never the issue. Vite just seems way more strict than webpack. This library is related to the DOM it's just that this polyfill is too ancient and shouldnt be in that library anyway.

What seems to work for me and my particular case is to patch this one particular package with patch-package. I've made a diff that changes
-  var window = this
+  var window = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : (typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : {});

I have been able to do a fresh install after removing /node_modules and i've been able to build this inside docker. I guess i was always able to build it, it's just that now it actually works and does not crash some page.
